# Mandrill: Authenticating a webhook in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, authentication, mandrill

I need to authenticate a mandrill webhook using PHP. I've followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583257-Authenticating-webhook-requests), but when I pass my $_POST data, it throws an error saying that I can't append an array into a string. I understand the error, but I couldn't find anything explaining how to overcome this problem. This is what I have now:

Signature generator provided by Mandrill.

```
/**
 * Generates a base64-encoded signature for a Mandrill webhook request.
 * @param string $webhook_key the webhook's authentication key
 * @param string $url the webhook url
 * @param array $params the request's POST parameters
 */
protected function generateSignature($webhook_key, $url, $params) {
    $signed_data = $url;
    ksort($params);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $signed_data .= $key;
        $signed_data .= $value;
    }

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signed_data, $webhook_key, true));
}
```

My json test data passed via POST method.

```
$jsonPost = ["mandrill_events" => '{
            "0": {
                "event": "hard_bounce",
                "msg": {
                    "ts": 1365109999,
                    "subject": "Thisanexamplewebhookmessage",
                    "email": "example@email.com",
                    "sender": "example.sender@mandrillapp.com",
                    "tags": [
                        "webhook-example"
                    ],
                    "opens": [],
                    "clicks": [],
                    "state": "sent",
                    "metadata": {
                        "user_id": 111
                    },
                    "_id": "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "_version": "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                },
                "_id": "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "ts": 1384954004
            }
        }'];
```

I am receiving this json data in the following structure.

```
Array ( [mandrill_events] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [event] => hard_bounce [msg] => Array ( [ts] => 1365109999 [subject] => Thisanexamplewebhookmessage [email] => example@email.com [sender] => example.sender@mandrillapp.com [tags] => Array ( [0] => webhook-example ) [opens] => Array ( ) [clicks] => Array ( ) [state] => sent [metadata] => Array ( [user_id] => 111 ) [_id] => exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [_version] => exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ) [_id] => exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [ts] => 1384954004 ) ) [responseType] => HTML )
```

How I'm calling generateSignature.

```
$signature = $this->generateSignature($webhook_key, $url, $_POST);
```

The error.

```
Error 8 in line 40 of ... . Array to string conversion 5
```

Where line 40 is:

```
$signed_data .= $value;
```

What could be the problem? Am I implementing something wrong?